# conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'unsigned int'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, comparison

For the following function in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC, I get two warnings regarding the comparison of signed and unsigned variables.

```
uint64_t findMin(vector<uint64_t> &v)
{
   uint64_t min = 0;
   uint64_t s = v.size();
   for (uint64_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
       if (v[i] != 0) {   // WARNING
           min = v[i];    // WARNING
           break;
       }
   }
   ...
 }
```

The warning is

```
warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

That is weird because at least I am sure that `min` and `v[i]` both have `uint64_t` variables and that is obvious.

Is that related to RC edition? or there is something behind that that I am unaware of that?

Comment: Your constants should have the appropriate suffixes.  The literal 0 is signed int by default.

Comment: Presumably size_t is a uint64_t as well?  I was thinking it was the index...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "argument" about which the compiler is warning is the `i` argument to `operator[]` in `v[i]` (note that this is the only argument on either of those lines).

The parameter of this `operator[]` overload is of type `size_t`.  In 32-bit builds `size_t` is a 32-bit unsigned integer.  Conversion of the 64-bit unsigned `i` to the 32-bit unsigned parameter type is a narrowing conversion.

Comment: Presumably "for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {}" is the way to go.  Or better "for (auto & x: v) {}"

Comment: The argument is actually `size_type`, which is usually the same as `size_t` but not necessarily.

Comment: @JCx Assuming we understand the intent of the code, then the way to go is to get rid of the function entirely and use `std::min_element`

Comment: Yup I changed the the build type to X64